# Can I export the result from a loess regression out of R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I have performed a loess regression on some data and plotted it. The problem is I'd like to export the black line and light red line (see figure) into excel. Is it possible?

Clarification:

I want to export the underlying data from the loess regression not the graph.

[image]

Code used to calculate it:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=bigangle, y=meanz, colour=treatment)) + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(y = X2/median(df$X2), x=X8),color="red",alpha=.6) +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(y = X2/median(df$X2),x=X8),fill="red", colour="black", size=1,alpha=0.4)+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.1),aes(shape=treatment),   # Shape depends on cond
             size = 4,colour="black",fill="black")
```

Comment: If you are using RStudio there is an "Export" drop down above the plot. Otherwise, look at the function `ggsave()`.

Comment: Ah yes, I should clarify. I mean I'd like to export the actual data that the loess generates so I can replot it in excel :-)

Comment: Fit a model using `loess`, create data at the resolution you want to export `new = data.frame(bigangle = seq(0, 360, by = 0.5))`, generate predictions, `new$loess_predict = predict(your_loess_model, newdata = new)`, and then save it as a CSV or whatever other file you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what loess function `ggplot2` uses, but here is one way to extract a loess object to graph in Excel:

```
# fake data
myData <- data.frame("x"=1:100, "y"=rnorm(100))
# loess object
my.loess <- loess(y~x, data=temp)
# get SE
myPred <- predict(my.loess, se=T)
my.output <- data.frame("fitted"=myPred$fit, "SE"=myPred$se.fit)

# write out data
write.csv(my.output, file=<path/filename>.csv)
```

Comment: `ggplot` uses `stats::loess` so this is exactly correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fantastic answer :-)

Comment: Hi Imo. I'm finding that my.output$fitted does not represent the black line in the graph above. Is it not supposed to? It thought it should do right?

Comment: There are many reasons that could be behind this. For example, how many observations do you have? Take a look at `?geom_smooth` after loading `ggplot2`. If you have more than 1000 observations, then `geom_smooth` uses a different function. There are a lot of parameters that can be adjusted in `?loess`. While I don't see any differences in comparing the help files something might be set to a different level.