# Exporting Loess smooth regression to CSV or Excel

Tags: r, ggplot2, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, loess

Hi I am an R newb trying to model out the performance of a few songs over several months. I have imported the data into a data frame called Top_Songs_transformed with 3 columns:

```
Track : Factor w/3 levels
Report.Date: Date, Format: <"YYYY-MM-DD">
Payment : Num  100 105 98 110 120 150
```

I have been able to do a loess regression in ggplot [in this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQL1C.png). I would like to export the values of the regression line to a csv or excel file.

[Here is a question which is similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987104/can-i-export-the-result-from-a-loess-regression-out-of-r) however, the results of using loess() function produced a graph which did not seem to match the loess curve on the graph linked above.

Here is what i have so for to export the regression results. I found that i had to transform the date values from my original data set into numeric vales. However aft when i exported the results the Y values looked nothing like the smooth line that I had in R.

```
ggplot(data = Top_songs_Transormed, aes( Report.Date, Payment ))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth( method = "loess" , se=TRUE)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 40000, 5000))+
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m-%Y")

#Extract loess values
#Need to convert dates to numerical values FML
Data_loess <- transform( Top_songs_Transormed, Report.Date= as.numeric(Top_songs_Transormed$Report.Date))
Songs.export <- loess(Payment ~ Report.Date, data = Data_loess)

write.csv2(as.data.frame(Songs.export), "C:/Users/User/Documents/TOP_CURVE_LOESS.csv", sep=",")
```

two main questions I have are:

1. How can you export the blue loess regression line?
2. How would you use this to predict future values?

Comment: If you want the fitted values, it's easier to use the `loess()` function.  `geom_smooth` has a few "built-in" methods for convenience, but that's just meant for exploring the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I export the result from a loess regression out of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987104/can-i-export-the-result-from-a-loess-regression-out-of-r)

Comment: @Vlo Thank you, I used that as the basis for what ive done... Do you know what I am doing wrong vs theirs?

Comment: Did you run the code in the linked answer?

Comment: @Vlo yes, except i did not try to export the Standard Error values. I just did Songs.export <- loess(Payment ~ Report.Date, data = Data_loess) and export the "y" values associated with the regression.

Comment: You are missing the crucial lines. Just do for the fitted values: `write.csv2(data.frame(fitted = predict(Songs.export, se=F)), blah blah your path)`

Comment: @Vlo That worked! thank you. i clearly didnt know what i was doing. What does the fitted = predict() do? I tried looking at the documentation and was confused about what a Raster object is?

Comment: `fitted` is just the name of the column within the data.frame. `predict(your loess curve)` returns the fitted (the values draw on the plot)

Comment: That helps, I can see the column name in the dataframe now. Thank you!