# Export results from LOESS plot

Tags: r, loess

I am trying to export the underlying data from a LOESS plot (blue line)
[image]

I found this post on the subject and was able to get it to export like the post says:
[Can I export the result from a loess regression out of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987104/can-i-export-the-result-from-a-loess-regression-out-of-r)

However, as the last comment from the poster in that post says, I am not getting the results for my LOESS line.  Does anyone have any insights on how to get it to export properly?

Thanks!

Code for my export is here:

```
#loess object
CL111_loess <- loess(dur_cleaned~TS_LightOn, data = CL111)

#get SE
CL111_predict <- predict(CL111_loess, se=T)

CL111_ouput <- data.frame("fitted" = CL111_predict$fit, "SE"=CL111_predict$se.fit)

write.csv(CL111_ouput, "CL111_output.csv")
```

Data for the original plot is [here](https://tufts.box.com/s/yhxv47kuavfa4mwuttrba667lljiwiu1):

Code for my original plot is here:

```
{r}

#individual plot
ggplot(data = CL111) + geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = TS_LightOn, y = dur_cleaned), method = "lm", se = FALSE, colour = "Green") +
labs(x = "TS Light On (Seconsd)", y = "TS Response Time (Seconds)", title = "Layout 1, Condition AO, INS High") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_smooth(mapping = aes(x = TS_LightOn, y = dur_cleaned), method = "loess", se = TRUE) + xlim(0, 400) + ylim (0, 1.0) 

#find coefficients for best fit line

lm(CL111_LM$dur_cleaned ~ CL111_LM$TS_LightOn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information via `ggplot_build()`.

If your plot is saved as `gg1`, run `ggplot_build(gg1)`; then you have to examine the `data` object (which is a list of data for different layers) and try to figure out which layer you need (in this case, I looked for which data layer included a `colour` column that matched the smooth line ...

```r
bb <- ggplot_build(gg1)
## extract the right component, just the x/y coordinates
out <- bb$data[[2]][,c("x","y")]
## check
plot(y~x, data = out)
```

You can do whatever you want with this output now (`write.csv()`, `save()`, `saveRDS()` ...)

[image: plot of loess points]

I agree that there is something weird/that I don't understand about the way that `ggplot2` is setting up the loess fit.  You do have to do `predict()` with the right `newdata` (e.g. a data frame with a single column `TS_LightOn` that ranges from 0 to 400) - otherwise you get predictions of the points in your data set, which may not be properly spaced/in the right order - but that doesn't resolve the difference for me.

Comment: Wow, that worked exactly how I needed it to! Thanks for taking the time to download my data and actually answering the question fully...it is very much appreciated. Have a great evening!

Answer (score 0):

To complement @ben-bolker, I have just written a small function that may be useful for retrieving the internal dataset created by ggplot for a geom_smooth call. It takes the resultant ggplot as input and returns the smoothed data. The problem it solves is that, as Ben observed, internally ggplot creates a smoothed fit with predicted data on random intervals, different from the interval used for the input data. This function will get you back the ggplot fit data with an interval based on integer and equally spaced values. That function uses a loess fit on the already smoothed data, using a small value of span (0.1), that is adjusted upward on-the-fly to cope with small numbers of values.

This is useful if you used geom_smooth with a method that is not 'loess' or using 'NULL' and you cannot easily build a model that replicates what geom_smooth is doing internally.

The function separates different series on the same plot as well as series located on different facets. It also returns the 'ymin' and 'ymax' values.

Note that this function uses an interval based on integer values of x. You can modify this if you need an interval based on equally-spaced values of x, but not integral. In that case, pass your x interval of choice in the xInterval parameter, or tweak the line:

outOne <- data.frame(x=c(min(trunc(sub$x)):max(trunc(sub$x)))).

```
get_geom_smooth_dataFromPlot <- function (a_ggplot, xInterval=NULL) {
  #internal ggplot values read in ggTable
  ggTable <- ggplot_build(a_ggplot)$data[[1]]
  #facet panels
  panels <- as.numeric(names(table(ggTable$PANEL)))
  nPanel <- length(panels)
  onePanel <- (nPanel==1)
  #number of series in each plot
  groups <- as.numeric(names(table(ggTable$group)))
  nGroup <- length(groups)
  oneGroup <- (nGroup==1)
  out <- data.frame()
  #are there 'ymin' and 'ymax' values?
  SE_data <- "ymin" %in% colnames(ggTable)
  for (pan in (1:nPanel)) {
    for (grp in (1:nGroup)) {
      sub <- subset(ggTable, (PANEL==panels[pan])&(group==groups[grp]))
      #no group series for this facet panel?
      if (dim(sub)[1] == 0) next
      if (is.null(xInterval)) {
        outOne <- data.frame(x=c(min(trunc(sub$x)):max(trunc(sub$x))))
      } else {
        outOne <- data.frame(x=xInterval)
      }
      nObs <- dim(outOne)[1]
      #hack to avoid problems with a small range for the x interval
      #  when there are more than 90 x values
      #  we use a span of 0.1, but
      #  we adjust on-the-fly up to a span of 0.5
      #  for 10 values of the x interval
      cSpan <- max (0.1, 0.5 * 10 / (nObs-(nObs-10)/2)) 
      if (!onePanel) outOne$panel <- pan
      if (!oneGroup) outOne$group <- grp
      mod <- loess(y~x, data=sub, span=cSpan)
      outOne$y <- predict(mod, outOne$x, se=FALSE)
      if (SE_data) {
        mod <- loess(ymin~x, data=sub, span=cSpan)
        outOne$ymin <- predict(mod, outOne$x, se=FALSE)
        mod <- loess(ymax~x, data=sub, span=cSpan)
        outOne$ymax <- predict(mod, outOne$x, se=FALSE)
      }
      out <- rbind(out, outOne)
    }
  }
  return (out)
}
```